# Ant zip change base dir to zip at different level

Tags: java, ant

I have an Ant zip task that looks like this:

```
<zip basedir="${workspace.dir}"
    destfile="${build.output.dir}/test.zip"
    includes="${eLibrary}/bin/com/**,
              ${Common}
    excludes="${eLibrary}/lib,
              ${eLibrary}/src"
     >
</zip>
```

The eLibrary folder has a structure similar to:

```
`--bin
    `--com
`--lib
`--src
```

I'd like to have the zip file look like this:

```
`--eLibrary
    `--com
`--Common
```

When the zip is created though it has the following structure:

```
`--eLibrary
    `--bin
        `--com
`--Common
```

I've tried various types of include statements, but they all include the `bin` folder:

```
includes="${eLibrary}/bin/**
includes="${eLibrary}/bin/com/**
includes="${eLibrary}/bin
includes="${eLibrary}/bin/com
```

Changing the basedir won't work because I also need the Common folder included.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the `zip` task [documentation](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/zip.html) for examples on how to achieve this. The below snippet uses a `zipfileset` nested element which maps the included entries to the directories inside the archive.

```
<zip destfile="${build.output.dir}/test.zip">
    <zipfileset dir="${eLibrary}/bin/com" prefix="${eLibrary}/com"/>
    <zipfileset dir="${Common}" prefix="${Common}"/>
</zip>
```